# Issue with animator in Unity 2d

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to solve an issue in Unity 2d game creation.
So, my issue is when the subject is idle, the 2d player object should be idle and when I move the character, it must animate like walking.

But in my case, the walking animation is not working but the character is moving.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    private float jumpmovement = 11f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float movement = 10f;
    private float movementx;
    [SerializeField]
    private Rigidbody2D mybody;
    private Animator anim;
    [SerializeField]
    private string Walk_Ani = "Player is walking";
    private SpriteRenderer sr;


    private void Awake()
    {
        mybody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        Playerkeymove();
        animateplayer1();
    }
    void Playerkeymove()
    {
        movementx = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        // Debug.Log(movementx);
        transform.position += new Vector3(movementx, 0f, 0f) * movement * Time.deltaTime;
        // Debug.Log(transform.position);
    }
    void animateplayer1()
    {
        // anim.SetBool(Walk_Ani , true);
        // we are going to the right side
        if (movementx > 0)
        {
            anim.SetBool(Walk_Ani, true);
            sr.flipX = false;
        }
        else if (movementx < 0)
        {
            // we are going to the left side
            anim.SetBool(Walk_Ani, true);
            sr.flipX = true;
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool(Walk_Ani, false);
        }
    }

}
```

I can't understand, why I have a warning issue with boolean part where I guess that's where my animation takes part.
[image]

Comment: can you share your animator controller screen and verify you have transition parameter with **Player is walking** name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set a boolean parameter in the Animator that doesn't exists. The code is correct. Check what name you choose for the bool parameter to active correctly the animation.